# Inserting a dump MySQL MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dump

I'm using DOCKER.
I have a file called `autoparanaiba.sql` at my Downloads folder and I would like to insert the dumps at my database. In this file, has the CREATE TABLE and etc... I found the command
`mysqldump -u username -p database_name > data-dump.sql` and I tried this

```
~/Downloads took 3s 
>mysqldump -u root -p autoparanaiba > autoparanaiba.sql
```

Appear to digit the PASSWORD, I tried the password that I put the database PW and printed this

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn’t start your database server.

Try starting/restarting your mysql server.

Comment: its docker, so this doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use mysqldump to load the database.

For docker in the docs under [Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/):

mkdir /tmp/datainit
mkdir datadir
mv ~/autoparanaiba.sql /tmp/datainit

```
docker run -v /tmp/datainit:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
      -v ./datadir:/var/lib/mysql
     mariadb
```

The datadir is the databases's data directory exposed as a volume so its preserved. `datainit` is where initialization files go.

Comment: I runned this command

```/usr/bin  took 3s 
>docker exec autoparanaiba mysqldump -u root --password=123456 autoparanaiba > ../../home/vagnerwentz/autoparanaiba.sql
```
But did nothing

Comment: I didn't understand what need to do.